# GET parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, get

I have an URL like http://www.test.pl/product-pol-4406.html

With Geasemonkey scripts I want to get the "4406" part from the URL, but I don`t have any idea how to do it. My code is:

```
var input=document.createElement("input"); 
input.type="button";
input.value="Edytuj";
input.alt="visitPage";
input.onclick = visitPage;
input.setAttribute("style", "font- size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:40px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

function visitPage(){
    window.location='https://test.pl/panel/product-edit.php?idt=4406';
}
```

Any suggestions? Please.

Answer (score 0):

use below function to get your **'idt'** value in javascript

```
 function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var result= = getParameterByName('idt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

To get the full URL. According to your needs you could parse the URL with regex afterwards to get what you need, or e.g. split it to get parts of it with a seperator that makes sense with the type of URLs you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the product id from the given url and then pass to the php page. You can try this

```
var url = "http://www.test.pl/product-pol-4406.html" //window.location.href

if(url){
    url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  var productID = url.match(/\d+/);
    alert(productID);
}
```

Update:

```
function getProductID(){
    var url = "http://www.test.pl/product-pol-4406.html" //window.location.href

    if(url){
        url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        return url.match(/\d+/);
    }
}
```

And then call the function inside the `visitePage()` function

```
function visitPage(){
    var productID = getProductID();
    if(productID){
        window.location='https://test.pl/panel/product-edit.php?idt='+productID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its work but how paste (productID) on: `code function visitPage(){
    window.location='https://test.pl/panel/product-edit.php?idt=productID';
}`

Comment: @mski, Updated the answer, hope this solves the problem

Comment: one more, it is possible open url in new_tab?

Comment: Sure, use `window.open('https://test.pl/panel/product-edit.php?idt='+productID);` instead `window.location', it opens in new window.